# flexbox for react app, column vs row

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-bootstrap

Hi I am struggling to understand Flexbox despite checking out lots of websites/documentation. I am trying to have a vertical navbar on the LHS of the screen (as per http://slackclone.herokuapp.com/ - need to sign in) and I am adding another vertical navbar on the RHS of screen.
The left .nav currently has

```
.nav {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background: #337ab7;
  width: 21rem;
-ms-flex: 0 1rem;
-webkit-box-flex:  0;
-moz-box-flex:  0;
-ms-box-flex:  0;
box-flex:  0;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

However, I am trying to set the right navbar as:

```
 .right-nav {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background: #337ab7;
  width: 25rem;
-ms-flex: 0 1rem;
-webkit-box-flex:  0;
-moz-box-flex:  0;
-ms-box-flex:  0;
box-flex:  0;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

However, the

```
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
```

from .nav is overriding the row direction in my .right-nav

Note: I need the flex direction to be row for right nav because I am trying to put in a tab component that line up horizontally. The current column direction in .nav is making the tab component stack vertically much to my frustration.
So my question is how do I have two navbars on a page where one uses column and another row. Or is there a better way to solve this with my Tabs.
Thanks

Comment: This is really helpful: http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: I have a feeling that this might just be about CSS selector precedence, which isn't necessarily related to flexbox and has nothing to do with react. It would be useful if you showed us a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: So do you want a horizontal navbar at the top and a vertical navbar at the left?

Comment: thanks for the frog game! but most tutorials online only cover a specific aspect of Flexbox,hard to find a comprehensive tutorial that covers more complicated layouts.

Comment: Try maybe developing a JSFiddle or codepen and add a sketch of what you would like to achieve and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Sometimes it's very difficult to extract code from an existing large app due to interdependencies btw modules etc and put it into CodePen etc I am currently looking at alternatives to flexbox that are more user friendly and can still provide a lot of control.Thanks!